# Using ProGuard with reflection for startBluetoothSCO() in an Android app

Tags: android, reflection, bluetooth, proguard

I'm using reflection to invoke the AudioManager.startBluetoothSco() method. It has to be done via reflection since it only exists in 2.2 or higher SDK, but my app is build for min version of 2.0. If I just compile my app without using ProGuard, everything works fine -- the metod gets invoked properly in 2.2, and not at all in lower versions. But when I use ProGuard, it doesn't work at all. I assume that there is a KEEP satement in ProGuard config that'll fix this, but I can't figure out what it should be. Here are the 3 lines from my code:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
Method startBT = AudioManager.class.getMethod("startBluetoothSco");   
startBT.invoke(am);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use lazy loading instead of reflections - it's faster and I think ProGuard will run fine, too:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

Here is a simple example of a current project of mine where I activate StrictMode (if available):

```
public abstract class StrictModeUtil {

    private static class GingerbreadAndBeyond extends StrictModeUtil {

        private static class Holder {
            private static final GingerbreadAndBeyond INSTANCE = new GingerbreadAndBeyond();
        }

        public GingerbreadAndBeyond() {
            // we just enable StrictMode here, but only in developer mode
            if (C.D) {
                android.os.StrictMode.enableDefaults();
            }
        }
    }

    public static StrictModeUtil getInstance() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            return GingerbreadAndBeyond.Holder.INSTANCE;
        } else {
            // we don't need an implementation before Android 2.3
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked out great. I haven't had a chance to test it with ProGuard yet, but if there are problems, I'll post them here